# Trying to create a bootable USB drive for Mac Mini

Tags: usb, mac-mini

I have a Mac Mini Late 2012.

Trying to create a bootable USB drive. I have a USB Yosemite install drive. It has worked, many times to load Yosemite to an internal drive.

I plugged this in to the mini, and a 64GB USB drive (a thumb drive), and proceeded to install Yosemite to the drive. I return to the computer, and the process seems complete, but on trying to boot to the newly created boot drive, the startup freezes halfway through.

I was hoping to use this USB drive for the occasion boot to use old software that no longer runs on newer OSes.

Comment: You would be better off purchasing a USB 3.0 HDD. You can get one for under 25 USD.

Comment: It was more a matter of curiosity about the process. Is there a technical reason this isn't working?

Comment: Ordinary flash drives are not designed for amount of writing that macOS would be preforming. Therefore using a flash drive is not practical. There are special flash drives built for operating systems designed for these flash drives such as Windows to Go. Apple has not produced a version of macOS that is designed for these kinds of flash drives. Many versions of Linux have the ability to run from a flash drive. However in these cases, Linux writes to a RAM drive instead of the flash drive. The contents of the RAM drive is read/written to the flash drive only when you boot/shutdown Linux.

Comment: Thanks for this level of detail. I'll quit that effort now. And will go the [SSD route](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/373275/booting-multiple-oses-on-mac-mini), an internal drive.