# Booting multiple OSes on Mac Mini

Tags: mojave, snow-leopard, mac-mini

I just got a 2012 MacMini, and it happens to be running Mojave. I'd like to easily boot into multiple OSes and have an SSD I can install into the Mac.

Before I make a huge mistake and waste a lot of time, I'd like to ask if the APFS file system of Mojave is going to be an issue. By this, I mean, can I still partition the SSD into 2-4 drives, and load each as I want? Will an old OS have an issue seeing the Mojave drive or vice versa?

Update - I installed an SSD, and it's running Mojave. I would still like to know if I'd be wasting my time partitioning the SSD to 2 partitions so I can use one with Yosemite and the other, Mojave. The exact question - "Can a partitioned drive have 2 file formats? One, APFS, the other, the 'old' Mac OS extended journaled (HFS?)?

Comment: Are you going to install a Mac OS prior to High Sierra?

Comment: Yes, I’d like to have Snow Leopard, Yosemite, and Mojave. I have a MacPro and used a similar setup, but stoping at High Sierra. A pretty fast boot into whichever OS I’d like to run.

Comment: So your mac already has a disk and you can add an SSD to it, great, partition them in a way that you can install OS's prior to High Sierra on a different disk because they are going to use HFS+ file system. Catalina works only on APFS so if you want to make it future-proof, format the other disk with APFS and you should be fine. As far as my knowledge goes, your mac will use the latest mac os recovery/bootloader installed on it, so as long as both disks are attached you won't have a problem booting into any OS. Hope this helps but be alarmed that I'm a newbie I hope an expert saves the day :)

Comment: Not 'adding'. I was going to pull the drive and replace it. Ideally, would run off one partitioned OS.

Comment: You can not install Snow Leopard on a 2012 Mac Mini. You *may* be able to install Snow Leopard in a virtual machine.

Comment: @DavidAnderson - Thanks. Yes. I should be embarrassed for not knowing this, or at least looking it up. 10.8.1 was the OS it shipped with.